# Unsmooth generated mesh in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, rendering

I'm trying to make a low poly terrain in unity, but for some weird reason it keeps smoothing it out. I tried removing Recalculate Normals, but that did not seem to help (also it wrecked the lighting). Please don't post any links to assets on the assets store.

Also using unity 2020.2.1f1

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind low poly mesh is to duplicate vertices to achieve sharp edges. When we normally create a mesh, it has ***N*** vertices. And when you recalculate normals, Unity generates exactly ***N*** normals. That means that for each angle in your mesh there is only one normal vector, which 3D engines try to smooth. So supposing a simplified 2D example, it looks something like this:

[image: Smooth edge]

Your goal instead is to duplicate vertex for each triangle, that this vertex belongs, so that each edge would be disjoint, and that would cause Unity to generate separate normals for each edge and sharp the angle. Like this:

[image: Sharp edge]

Unfortunately, there is no way to create multiple normals for one vertex, that's because you'd have to duplicate them. So for example you want to create a mesh with two triangles with a sharp edge. In code it would be something similar to this:

```cs
var mesh = new Mesh();

// Basically amount of your vertices is equal to amount of indices.
var vertices = new Vector3[6];
var triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// Define first triangle.
vertices[0] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
vertices[1] = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
vertices[2] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

// Define second triangle
vertices[3] = vertices[2];    // Duplicating vertex #2.
vertices[4] = vertices[1];    // Duplicating vertex #1.
vertices[5] = new Vector3(-1, 0, 1);

mesh.vertices = vertices;
mesh.triangles = triangles;
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

Also check this article, it describes nicely behaviour of shading in 3D engines depending on shared and separated vertices: [Tutorial 9: VBO Indexing](https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/)

Update: As mentioned in the comments you can also try to use Flat shading model. But as far as I know, it might be not supported on some platforms.

Comment: you might want to mention that this depends on the shading model used. I.e. Gouraud shading vs flat shading.

Comment: @JonasH My bad. Indeed, you can also use flat shading. But since we do not know what is the OP's target platform, and since flat shading is not something supported on every platform, separating vertices is more generic solution.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I just thought it a good idea to mention the terms since the OP did not seem to know about them.

Comment: I know this naming paradox was introduced by OP ... but saying you create a **low poly** mesh by adding more vertices sounds a bit funny ;) What is ment is the flat/sharp edge rendering of course but I'd guess to duplicate the edges of a terrain would create a lot of new Mesh data and slow down the rendering a lot